# Python.Can I remove the Frame in the Turtle Python Graphics window?

Tags: tkinter

I'm using Python 3.10 .I Using Turtle and Tkinter.Can I remove the Frame in the Turtle Python Graphics window?
For example:

```
from turtle import *
from tkinter  import *
canvas=getcanvas()
root=canvas.master
root.configure(bg="white")
forward(100)
Label(root,text="123").pack()
```

I tried to use Tkinter and Turtle. I thought there would be no frame. How can I remove the frame?

Answer (score 0):

You can set the border width (`bd` or `borderwidth` option) of the canvas to zero to remove the *frame* (actually it is the border of the canvas) by calling

```
canvas.config(bd=0, highlightthickness=0)
```